# How can i import string from nltk.corpus?

Tags: python, nltk, nlp

I am trying to load string from nltk.corpus module. But i am getting an error.

from nltk.corpus import string
[image: See error in this image]

Would any of you be kind enough to guide me here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't post images. Provide it in text.

Comment: Can you describe the functionality you are trying to access, since `string` is not in `nltk.corpus`?

Comment: @readyready15728 I tried the wrong syntax.@anggriyulio helped me on this one. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sub module called string in NLTK.corpus.
Please check this page http://www.nltk.org/py-modindex.html